# xslt/xml byte array, to a image

Tags: sql, image, xslt

I am getting back a image from SQL server as a byte[]. Can I use xsl transform to convert it into an actual image for a webpage? How, may I do so if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got around via a recomendation by my coworker using:

```
return File(myImage.ImageBinary, "image/gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I can't see a relation between an image and an XSL transformation. Are you using an SVG image?

If you are storing something like a JPEG image, you could create an ASP.NET Handler that fetches that from DB as a `byte[]` and use `Response.BinaryWrite` method to stream that to the client.